# Suppress Mathematica Kernel taskbar tab when using .NETLink

Tags: mathlink-or-wstp, .netlink, windows

Is there a possibility to suppress the Mathematica Kernel taskbar tab when accessing it through .NETLink on Windows?

Comment: Welcome.  There is no need to sign your messages; that is what the user block below each post and your profile are for.

Comment: This is not really .NETLink related: the question is if there's a command line option that'll prevent the kernel from showing itself in the taskbar (BTW I think this behaviour is deliberate, ad not an oversight, though I can completely understand why someone would want to hide it).

Answer (score 7):

The command line option to call the kernel with to suppress the taskbar button is `-noicon`.  You need to pass this flag to `MathKernel.exe` [when launching it](http://reference.wolfram.com/legacy/v7/NETLink/ref/net/Wolfram.NETLink.MathLinkFactory.CreateKernelLink_overloads.html).

Here's a demonstration from within Mathematica:

```
kernel = LinkLaunch[First[$CommandLine] <> " -mathlink -noicon"]
```

This will launch a new kernel and connect to it.  On Windows, the new kernel will not show on the taskbar.

<sup>I do not remember where I learned about this command line flag.  It took me quite a few minutes to be able to recall it at all.</sup>

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Unfortunately the taskbar button sill appears. I've got the following code:
Dim _arguments As String = "-linkmode launch -linkname ""C:/Program Files/Mathematica/8.0/MathKernel.exe"" -noicon"
_iKernelLink = Wolfram.NETLink.MathLinkFactory.CreateKernelLink(_arguments)
Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: @alxppp I don't know C#, can you first try the Mathematica code I posted?  If that one works, we can go from there.

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply. Your Mathematica code works, no Kernel button appears in the taskbar after execution.

Comment: @alxppp I don't know Visual Basic or any .NET, but my guess is that you need to launch the kernel using `Wolfram.NETLink.MathLinkFactory.CreateKernelLink("-noicon")`

Comment: Thank you. This is what the code from my first comment does. I just put the arguments of the CreateKernelLink function in a separate string variable ("_arguments").

Comment: Just another guess: try to make the -noicon be part of the linkname option (e.g. `"-linkmode launch -linkname ""C:\...\MathKernel.exe -noicon"""`). What you do at the moment looks like you provide another option to CreateKernelLink but the Kernel probably doesn't see it at all.

Comment: Thanks for your guess, Albert. Sadly this doesn't work either; the Kernel does not start up. I also tried, creating a shortcut to the MathKernel.exe with the -noicon argument, but it does not work, even if it works when clicking it in the Windows Explorer.