# Hide MathKernel Tab on Taskbar when using C++

Tags: programming, mathlink-or-wstp, windows, c++

I am connecting to MathKernel.exe using C++ via MathLink on Windows. Hence, to create the link, this is what I use:

```
link = MLOpenString(env, "-linkmode launch -linkname 'C:\\Program Files\\Wolfram Research\\Mathematica\\9.0\\MathKernel.exe -mathlink'", &errno);
```

Once the link is successfully launched, MathKernel's tab appears on the taskbar. Can we suppress that? Is there a way?

Comment: Let me know if that works from the link above.  More explicitly, use `"-linkmode launch -linkname 'C:\\Program Files\\Wolfram Research\\Mathematica\\9.0\\MathKernel.exe -mathlink -noicon'"`  I'm not using Windows any more so I can't easily test this.

Comment: yes, this works perfectly fine! thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

instead, use

```
"-linkmode launch -linkname 'C:\\Program Files\\Wolfram Research\\Mathematica\\9.0\\MathKernel.exe -mathlink -noicon'"
```

with reference to [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/1450/suppress-mathematica-kernel-taskbar-tab-when-using-netlink)